# Map Maker Game Question- How can I select image and display on map tiles

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am stuck on this Map Maker game where I need to select the icons and then paste/display them on the map tiles. Which functions/event listeners can allow me to do that. Please let me know as soon as possible. Use the image below to understand what I mean. Thanks in advance.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVMUF.png

```js
//Detect when a person clicks on a Mountain icon
const MountainIconClicked = (evt) => {
    console.log("Mountain Icon Pressed")
    if (evt.target.MountainIconClicked === tileMapClicked) {
        //stuck on this part!
    }
}
document.querySelector("#MountainIcon").addEventListener("click", MountainIconClicked)

//Detect when a person clicks on a Water icon
const WaterIconClicked = () => {
    console.log("Water Icon Pressed")
}
document.querySelector("#WaterIcon").addEventListener("click", WaterIconClicked)

//Detect when person clicks on tile map
const tileMapClicked = (evt) => {
    console.log("Person clicked on Tile Map")
}
document.querySelector("#tile-map").addEventListener("click", tileMapClicked)

//Detect when person clicks on Create New Map
const AddNewMap = () => {
    console.log("Create New Map Pressed")
}
document.querySelector("#NewMap").addEventListener("click", AddNewMap)
```

```html
<style>
        .tile {
            height: 64px;
            width: 64px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            background-color: #92d474;
        }
        
        img {
          width: 25px;
          height: 25px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">

    <header>
        <h1>Map Maker</h1>
        <button id="NewMap">CREATE NEW MAP</button>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h2>Select a Map Tile</h2>

        <div id="Icon">

            <div id="MountainIcon">
                <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/mountain-icon-minimal-design-flat-logo-illustration-146476885.jpg">
            </div>

            <div id="WaterIcon">
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/virtaa/virtaa1509/virtaa150900148/45332573-water-drop-thin-line-icon-modern-minimal-flat-design-style-vector-illustration.jpg">
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <h2>Your Map</h2>

        <div id="tile-map">
            <!-- row 1   -->
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>

            <!-- row 2  -->
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>

            <!-- row 3   -->
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>

        </div>

    </footer>
```

Comment: I don't see the "image below" you mentioned.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVMUF.png

Comment: @Nada Please edit your post and add the image.

Comment: Yes, I posted the link. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the ability to place tiles is already working but the ability to choose which tile type to place is not. Is that right?

Comment: Yes I have my tiles and Icons already set up like the image. But I'm not sure which functions can allow me to select the icon that I want and allow me to place it on specific tiles.

Comment: like how can I get my code to work where I can select the mountain tile and then paste it on the tiles map??

Comment: Step one is to setup a click handler for the map tiles so that when a tile is clicked, your handler function gets called. Next step is to make that handler function change the clicked tile's picture (to mountains say). Once you've got that working then you can think about how to make which tile type gets placed dynamic (so not always mountains).

Comment: This is what I have so far:  //Detect when a person clicks on a Mountain icon
const MountainIconClicked = (evt) =>{
    console.log ("Mountain Icon Pressed")

    if (evt.target.MountainIconClicked === tileMapClicked) {
        
        //stuck on this part!
    }
}
document.querySelector("#MountainIcon").addEventListener("click", MountainIconClicked)

Comment: So when a tile is clicked your handler function gets called (step one) but doesn't change the tile's picture (step two). Is that right?

Comment: and I also have an event listener for the tiles: //Detect when person clicks on tile map
const tileMapClicked = (evt) =>{
    console.log("Person clicked on Tile Map")
}
document.querySelector("#tile-map").addEventListener("click", tileMapClicked)
  Am I on the right track??

Comment: Oh good you have code to show. You should edit your question to show your code.

Comment: yes im stuck on step 2

Comment: `evt.target` is the element you clicked on so you just need to set that element's `src` attribute to the mountains picture path. Something like `evt.target.setAttribute('src', 'mountains.jpg')`. I'm assuming the clicked element is an `<img>` element here.

Comment: okay I see what your saying

Comment: would I even need a for loop for that? Im just trying to figure out how to do this because I haven't seen an example like it

Comment: No need for a loop but you probably need to change the query selector string so it selects each tile (rather than the element containing all the map tiles).

Comment: It would help if you could show your html code as well.

Comment: Im still confused on how I can click on an image icon then click on a tile and paste that same image using eventlisteners. Do you know of any games that have the same concept or other examples

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do the bit you're stuck on.

```js
const map = document.querySelector('#tile-map');

map.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/mountain-icon-minimal-design-flat-logo-illustration-146476885.jpg")');
});
```

```css
.tile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background-image: url("https://previews.123rf.com/images/virtaa/virtaa1509/virtaa150900148/45332573-water-drop-thin-line-icon-modern-minimal-flat-design-style-vector-illustration.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
Click a tile.
<div id="tile-map">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```